# Ising model with fixed length

Tags: statistical-mechanics, phase-transition, ising-model

Someone made the comment for an Ising model that:

> When finite  length  is fixed for a rectangular Ising model, there still is no phase transition.

How do they know this?

EDIT: To make the question more precise, taken from a comment of the OP below:

> Sorry, let me state the question explicitly: for a ferromagnetic Ising model with length and width of N and f(N)=N spins, respectively, Tc > 0. But for width of f(N)=constant, Tc=0. So for f(N)=N^x, at what value of x does Tc become > 0. If the answer is x=infinity, then why would x=1 result in Tc > 0, since f(N)=N^1=N and Tc > 0 for this case?

Comment: Who made a comment where?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch: I don't think it's an exact duplicate — this question is asking how to derive this result, while the other is asking for a generalization of this result.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert If you read the comments by the OP under the answer below, you'll see (at least that's what I understand) that he/she wants to know exactly the same: How do horizontal/vertical length have to be related in the Ising model to have a phase transition.  (Of course, it'd be nice if the OP would edit this into their question.)

Comment: @NorbertSchuch:  Ah, I see that now.  I was commenting from the review queue where answers aren't visible.

Answer (score 0):

For any finite system, the partition function is an analytic function of the (inverse) temperature, as well as any other parameter. Thus, there are no discontinuities in any derivative of the partition function, and thus there is no phase transition.

Comment: But for an NxN system, Tc > 0 (i.e. Onsager's exact soln). How can you calculate at what length M for an NxM system that Tc becomes > 0?

Comment: Specifically where M is a function of N, such as M=N^x

Comment: There's no phase transition for a finite system. The transition only occurs in the limit $N\to\infty$.

Comment: Sorry, let me state the question explicitly: for a ferromagnetic Ising model with length and width of N and f(N)=N spins, respectively, Tc > 0. But for width of f(N)=constant, Tc=0. So for f(N)=N^x, at what value of x does Tc become > 0. If the answer is x=infinity, then why would x=1 result in Tc > 0, since f(N)=N^1=N and Tc > 0 for this case?

Comment: @rookEqueen: there will be a phase transition in the thermodynamic limit, along any sequence of volumes (rectangular or not) that converges to the infinite lattice; moreover, the critical temperature will always be the same (it is a property of the limiting infinite system). So, in your example, any $f(N)$ converging to infinity when $N\to\infty$ will lead to $T_c>0$.

Comment: @rookEqueen Please use the **edit** function to edit clarifications into your question, rather than adding more and more comments.  As Yvan Velenik points out, the phase transition will only happen in the limit of $N\to\infy$; if I get your question correctly you are asking how the relative size of $N_x$ and $N_y$ has to be chosen in order to get a phase transition.  (Answer: It does not matter, as long as both go jointly to $\infty$.)